# Stop sending normal HTML upon PHP error?

Tags: php, html

If I have a PHP script with a starting and ending `<?php /* stuff */ ?>` tag, and with standard HTML after this, is it possible to tell the server to stop sending the normal HTML if for example, the script catches an error?

Example...

```
<?php
// ... rest of the script above here

$buildout = '(compiler output will display here)';
$execsout = '(program output will display here)';

// ... errors would be displayed here using die();
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<!-- rest of the HTML below here -->
```

What needs to happen, is for the script to die() while it is still processing the PHP part, then NOT send any HTML. The reason being, there is simply too much HTML to echo/print using PHP itself, and it makes editing much more cumbersome.

Comment: `die` should do exactly what you want. Did you try it?

Comment: And this is why we separate logic from presentation people. Watch and learn!

Comment: `die();` and `exit();` should do exactly what you want. Just like @dave said... I like to use `exit();`, at it isn't so morbid... Funny how `execute();` is also pretty morbid.

Comment: @Arian off-topic but the word "execute" originally referred to performing a task. The morbid meaning comes from that: performing the task of killing a person who had been sentenced to death (I assume that became "execute" as an innuendo). Here's a rough citation: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use php the status code as a response **header():**

```
if ($error)
{
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
 exit();
}

or 

header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work. I actually hadn't thought of throwing a server error, but it makes sense and ALMOST satisfies the requirements. The only thing would be so that if the PHP has already sent HTML, not to send the rest. But this is not important.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
if (!$error):
?>
    <!--- HTML here --->
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Also an excellent answer. I would vote this as a second best-answer if I could. To anyone else looking at the question, this is probably the best answer. But for my purposes, being able to send server errors is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can make every error fatal by making the **[Error Handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)** throw exceptions:

```
<?php
/**
 * throw exceptions based on E_* error types
 */
set_error_handler(function ($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_file, $err_line, array $err_context)
{
    // error was suppressed with the @-operator
    if (0 === error_reporting()) { return false;}
    throw new ErrorException("A $err_severity had occurred: $err_msg");
});
```

Note that this would make everything fatal, including warnings and notices, and completely halt your script.

Comment: This isn't a great idea resource/semantic wise. Plus, `exit` or `die` are probably what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I'd say a public-facing script shouldn't be causing these sorts of errors at all, even if it is handling them.

Comment: @Dave - Yes, the script wouldn't be making errors per se, but just in case something comes up that it needs to handle where I don't want the rest of the page to show. Like a MASSIVE HTML form below the PHP statements that should NOT show if the form is submitted and certain conditions are true.

Comment: In that case the answer you accepted really is the correct one. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

many great answers here, @TheWolf answer is what i would use, but exit and die are valid too.

if your script is generating errors, then you need to handler them appropriately. are you expecting your script to fail sometimes?

if you do a throw new ErrorException, place in try catch block